# How to implement virtual methods in Python?

Tags: python, virtual-functions

I know virtual methods from PHP or Java.

How can they be implemented in Python?

Or have I to define an empty method in an abstract class and override it?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Sure, and you don't even have to define a method in the base class. In Python methods are better than virtual - they're completely dynamic, as the typing in Python is *duck typing*.

```
class Dog:
  def say(self):
    print "hau"

class Cat:
  def say(self):
    print "meow"

pet = Dog()
pet.say() # prints "hau"
another_pet = Cat()
another_pet.say() # prints "meow"

my_pets = [pet, another_pet]
for a_pet in my_pets:
  a_pet.say()
```

`Cat` and `Dog` in Python don't even have to derive from a common base class to allow this behavior - you gain it for free. That said, some programmers prefer to define their class hierarchies in a more rigid way to document it better and impose *some* strictness of typing. This is also possible - see for example the [`abc` standard module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html).

Comment: `cat.say()` should be `another_pet.say()`

Comment: +1 for an example.  In what language do dogs say "hau" by the way?

Comment: @JeremyP: hmm, good point :-) I guess in languages where "h" is understood as making the sound like the first letter of "hippy", or of "Javier" in Spanish.

Comment: @Eli:  Sorry, but I was seriously interested in the answer to the question.  In English they say "woof", well they don't but that is the word we use analogous to "meow" for cats and "moo" for cows.  Is "hau" Spanish then?

Comment: @JeremyP I know for sure that's what Polish dogs say ;)

Comment: @JeremyP yes I confirm dogs say "Jau" in Spanish and when written in english would be "Hau" :) hth

Comment: @JeremyP In Portuguese, the onomatopoeia for the dog's barking is "au", which sounds exactly like the OP's "hau".  Edit: "au" sounds like the "ow" in the English word "how".

Comment: @JeremyP, in Polish dogs say literally "Hau" and cats say "Miau".

Comment: I wonder how Polish and English dogs talk to each other? Do they have their own version of google translate, or do they just use body language like human tourists do?

Comment: In Spanish dogs say "guau" or "wuau" and cats say "miau". Also roosters say "kikiriki", which baffles a lot of non spanish speakers.
I heard there's a conference coming up to officialize "woofperanto", so dogs can finally communicate in this globalized world ;)

Comment: Confirming that in Hebrew it's "Hau" as well (at least, this is a good transcription for האו).

Answer (score 115):

Summary of current implementation status with a focus on "blowup nicely if the method is not implemented" behavior:

| methd | exception | mypy static | sphinx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `raise NotImplementedError()` | on method call | n | n |
| [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) | n | y | n |
| `@abc.abstractmethod` | on instantiation | y | y |

**`raise NotImplementedError()`: dynamic type checking**

This is the recommended exception to raise on "pure virtual methods" of "abstract" base classes that don't implement a method.

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/exceptions.html#NotImplementedError says:

> This exception is derived from `RuntimeError`. In user defined base classes, abstract methods should raise this exception when they require derived classes to override the method.

As others said, this is mostly a documentation convention and is not required, but this way you get a more meaningful exception than a missing attribute error.

dynamic.py

```
class Base(object):
    def virtualMethod(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()
    def usesVirtualMethod(self):
        return self.virtualMethod() + 1

class Derived(Base):
    def virtualMethod(self):
        return 1

assert Derived().usesVirtualMethod() == 2
Base().usesVirtualMethod()
```

gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dynamic.py", line 13, in <module>
    Base().usesVirtualMethod()
  File "./dynamic.py", line 6, in usesVirtualMethod
    return self.virtualMethod() + 1
  File "./dynamic.py", line 4, in virtualMethod
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
```

**`typing.Protocol`: static type checking (Python 3.8)**

Python 3.8 added [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) which now allows us to also statically type check that a virtual method is implemented on a subclass.

protocol.py

```
from typing import Protocol

class Bird(Protocol):
    def fly(self) -> str:
        pass

    def peck(self) -> str:
        return 'Bird.peck'

class Pigeon(Bird):
    def fly(self):
        return 'Pigeon.fly'

    def peck(self):
        return 'Pigeon.peck'

class Parrot(Bird):
    def fly(self):
        return 'Parrot.fly'

class Dog(Bird):
    pass

pigeon = Pigeon()
assert pigeon.fly() == 'Pigeon.fly'
assert pigeon.peck() == 'Pigeon.peck'
parrot = Parrot()
assert parrot.fly() == 'Parrot.fly'
assert parrot.peck() == 'Bird.peck'
# mypy error
dog = Dog()
assert dog.fly() is None
assert dog.peck() == 'Bird.peck'
```

If we run this file, the asserts pass, as we didn't add any dynamic typechecking:

```
python protocol.py
```

but if we typecheck if `mypy`:

```
python -m pip install --user mypy
mypy protocol.py
```

we get an error as expected:

```
rotocol.py:31: error: Cannot instantiate abstract class "Dog" with abstract attribute "fly"  [abstract]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

It is a bit unfortunate however that the error checking only picks up the error on instantiation, and not at class definition.

**`typing.Protocol` counts methods as abstract when their body is "empty"**

I'm not sure what they count as empty, but both all of the following count as empty:

- `pass`
- `...` ellipsis object
- `raise NotImplementedError()`

So the best possibility is likely:

protocol_empty.py

```
from typing import Protocol

class Bird(Protocol):
    def fly(self) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError()

class Pigeon(Bird):
    def fly(self):
        return None

class Dog(Bird):
    pass

Bird().fly()
Dog().fly()
```

which fails as desired:

```
protocol_empty.py:14: error: Cannot instantiate protocol class "Bird"  [misc]
protocol_empty.py:15: error: Cannot instantiate abstract class "Dog" with abstract attribute "fly"  [abstract]
protocol_empty.py:15: note: "fly" is implicitly abstract because it has an empty function body. If it is not meant to be abstract, explicitly `return` or `return None`.
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

but if e.g. we replace the:

```
raise NotImplementedError()
```

with some random "non-empty" statement such as:

```
x = 1
```

then `mypy` does not count them as virtual and gives no errors.

**`@abc.abstractmethod`: dynamic + static + documentation in one go**

Previously mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19316077/895245  but the `metaclass` syntax changed in Python 3 to:

```
class C(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
```

instead of the Python 2:

```
class C:
    __metaclass__=abc.ABCMeta
```

so now to use `@abc.abstractmethod` which was previously mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19316077/895245 you need:

abc_cheat.py

```
import abc

class C(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def m(self, i):
        pass

try:
    c = C()
except TypeError:
    pass
else:
    assert False
```

Vs `raise NotImplementedError` and `Protocol`:

- disadvantage: more verbose
- advantage: does all of dynamic checks, static checks and shows up on documentation (see below)

https://peps.python.org/pep-0544 does mention both approaches in passing

E.g.:

abc_bad.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import abc

class CanFly(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    '''
    doc
    '''

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def fly(self) -> str:
        '''
        doc
        '''
        pass

class Bird(CanFly):
    '''
    doc
    '''

    def fly(self):
        '''
        doc
        '''
        return 'Bird.fly'

class Dog(CanFly):
    '''
    doc
    '''
    pass

def send_mail(flyer: CanFly) -> str:
    '''
    doc
    '''
    return flyer.fly()

assert send_mail(Bird()) == 'Bird.fly'
assert send_mail(Dog()) == 'Dog.fly'
```

then:

```
mypy abc_bad.py
```

fails as desired with:

```
main.py:40: error: Cannot instantiate abstract class "Dog" with abstract attribute "fly"
```

**Sphinx: make it show on the documentation**

See: [How to annotate a member as abstract in Sphinx documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841323/how-to-annotate-a-member-as-abstract-in-sphinx-documentation)

Of the methods mentioned above, only one shows up on the sphinx documentation output: `@abc.abstractmethod`.

[image]

**Outro**

Bibiography:

- https://peps.python.org/pep-0544 the `typing.Protocol` PEP
- [Is it possible to make abstract classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646245/is-it-possible-to-make-abstract-classes-in-python)
- [What to use in replacement of an interface/protocol in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022766/what-to-use-in-replacement-of-an-interface-protocol-in-python)

Tested on Python 3.10.7, mypy 0.982, Ubuntu 21.10.

Answer (score 59):

Python methods are always virtual.

Comment: Except for dunder methods.

Comment: This answer is not really helping in the objective of implementing interface classes which is one of the main reason for using virtual methods.

Answer (score 25):

Actually, in version 2.6 python provides something called **abstract base classes** and you can explicitly set virtual methods like this:

```
from abc import ABCMeta
from abc import abstractmethod
...
class C:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    @abstractmethod
    def my_abstract_method(self, ...):
```

It works very well, provided the class does not inherit from classes that already use metaclasses.

source: http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html

Comment: Is there a python 3 equivalent for this directive?

Comment: @locke14 metaclass syntax changed in Python 3, now you have to write `class C(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta)`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38717503/895245

Answer (score 11):

> Python methods are always virtual

like Ignacio said yet
Somehow class inheritance may be a better approach to implement what you want.

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self,name,legs):
        self.name = name
        self.legs = legs

    def getLegs(self):
        return "{0} has {1} legs".format(self.name, self.legs)

    def says(self):
        return "I am an unknown animal"

class Dog(Animal): # <Dog inherits from Animal here (all methods as well)

    def says(self): # <Called instead of Animal says method
        return "I am a dog named {0}".format(self.name)

    def somethingOnlyADogCanDo(self):
        return "be loyal"

formless = Animal("Animal", 0)
rover = Dog("Rover", 4) #<calls initialization method from animal

print(formless.says()) # <calls animal say method

print(rover.says()) #<calls Dog says method
print(rover.getLegs()) #<calls getLegs method from animal class
```

Results should be:

```
I am an unknown animal
I am a dog named Rover
Rover has 4 legs
```

Answer (score 9):

Something like a virtual method in C++ (calling method implementation of a derived class through a reference or pointer to the base class) doesn't make sense in Python, as Python doesn't have typing. (I don't know how virtual methods work in Java and PHP though.)

But if by "virtual" you mean calling the bottom-most implementation in the inheritance hierarchy, then that's what you always get in Python, as several answers point out.

Well, almost always...

As dplamp pointed out, not all methods in Python behave like that. Dunder method don't. And I think that's a not so well known feature.

Consider this artificial example

```
class A:
    def prop_a(self):
        return 1
    def prop_b(self):
        return 10 * self.prop_a()

class B(A):
    def prop_a(self):
        return 2
```

Now

```
>>> B().prop_b()
20
>>> A().prob_b()
10
```

However, consider this one

```
class A:
    def __prop_a(self):
        return 1
    def prop_b(self):
        return 10 * self.__prop_a()

class B(A):
    def __prop_a(self):
        return 2
```

Now

```
>>> B().prop_b()
10
>>> A().prob_b()
10
```

The only thing we've changes was making `prop_a()` a dunder method.

A problem with the first behavior can be that you can't change the behavior of `prop_a()` in the derived class without impacting the behavior of `prop_b()`. [This](https://youtu.be/HTLu2DFOdTg) very nice talk by Raymond Hettinger gives an example for a use case where this is inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.6 introduced [`__init_subclass__`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0487/) and this let you simply do this:

```
class A:

    def method(self):
        '''method needs to be overwritten'''
        return NotImplemented

    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        if cls.method is A.method:
            raise NotImplementedError(
                'Subclass has not overwritten method {method}!')
```

The benefit of this solution is that you avoid the abc metaclass and give the user a direct imperative how to do it right. In addition to another answer here that raises `NotImplementedError` when calling the method. This solution is checked on runtime and not only IF the user calls the method.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual is not same as implementing abstract in inheriting child class.

Virtual supposed to be **used with Interface contract, where you can give the code a bit extra flexibility** and still gain the benefits of low-code duplication since the parent class can implement the basic function implementation that applies to 9/10 of your classes and through virtual you can override the 1/10 without needing to duplicate your functions in child-classes x,y or n because of the abstract definition would require you to do*.

I doubt there is any robust solution to support virtual in Python unluckily, as even the interfaces are not yet as part of the built-in modules (abc module, even often used to imitate interfaces, cannot really be considered as proper interface support).

*Software design quality-wise speaking it is one technique that can be used to move code towards low coupling, high cohesion quality goals, that lead to anti-spaghetti and eventually to code generation and fully generic modular coding philosophy, that is written as an generative engine, rather than custom implementation. There are many OOP programmers who claim OOP cannot be generated from the scratch due its "nature", the OOP is not supposed to be anything else than generated actually, especially if you do all of it before runtime (generate the whole runtime code in between), the better.

In case of instantiating new objects, you can enable high perf just like done in graphic rendering libraries. Generating an object blitter, to handle sudden needs for objects + on top library that handles management for such/orchestrates such real-time performance critical needs. Also, depending on your use-case, you can store them in high-perf data-structures such as Stacks, or List/Dict of Stacks incase you need to group them.