# How are pure virtual methods implemented in Python?

Tags: python, pure-virtual, virtual-functions

I have not found how yet. Meanwhile am currently using like this:

```
@abc.abstractmethod
def pure_virtual_method(self, a, b):
    """
      Method description.
      :param a: Whatever...
      :param b: Whatever...
      :returns: Whatever...
    """
    #   This line should never be executed.
    raise NotImplementedError(
        'pure virtual method specification called instead of any '
        'implementation')
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714136/python-how-to-implement-virtual-methods

Comment: Argh, I hate it when the better question has the worse or fewer answers. At least this question has made an attempt.

Comment: And so? What is missing in this for the behavior you want? Just the words "pure " and "virtual"?

Comment: This would mean that after ten years I finally ended up learning how to develop, if it wasn't a snippet of code compliant with a language designed for its code to be canonical... It's more desirable annotating with something like '@abc.trulyabstractmethod', just using a 'pass' statement instead of raising an exception, requiring this syntax, and not letting the code start the execution, instead of raising an exception in a process already executing the user code.