# How do I suggest methods to override in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance

Let's say I define a base class that provides some methods that will likely be overridden. It's not required though, as the base class provides naive default implementations. How can I highlight those methods best?

In C++, I would just use `virtual` but Python is a dynamic language where methods can always be overridden without marking them. I am rather looking for a hint here. Ideally, this is faster to see than a textual explanation in the docstring and easier to understand to others than a custom decorator.

Comment: expressive docstrings? a decorator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - how to implement virtual methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714136/python-how-to-implement-virtual-methods)

Comment: @dave It's not a duplicate. Python methods are always virtual but I'm looking for a way to *suggest* to override methods to developers inheriting from my class.

Comment: @oldrinb Thanks. Both are valid options, but have their downsides as I pointed out in the updated question. Is there a better solution?

Comment: A decorator that issues a warning upon (first) method invocation? Something like [@deprecated](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/391367-deprecated/)

Comment: I think an example or two would make your question more clear... or at least, your intent.  When you "suggest" a method for overriding, are you trying to say something like "subclasses may not override anything _but_ this", or something less strict, like "subclasses will find overriding _this_ more useful than overriding other methods"?  (On re-reading, I see you're not interested in the third option, "subclasses _must_ override this", but I'll leave it here for completeness.)

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase The last case, "subclasses might find it useful to override this", is exactly what I mean. An alternative would be to prevent all other methods from being overridden, but that possibility is not provided in Python.

Comment: From what (little) I've seen, methods like this are highlighted and explained in the documentation, not with any language feature.