# Why we need corresponding class function with each method in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, python-3.x, oop

I am learning OOP in python and following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python) stackoverflow answers and [this post](http://www.programiz.com/article/python-self-why)

I understood how class works and how method called and all things but i have some doubts:

Consider this fragment of code:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


    def distance(self):
         print (self.x)

    def bye(self):
        print(self.y)

a=Point(1,2)
a.distance()
a.bye()
```

As i read in tutorial :

> when we call a method with some arguments, the corresponding class
>   function is called by placing the method's object before the first
>   argument. So, anything like obj.meth(args) becomes Class.meth(obj,
>   args).
>
> when ObjectA.methodA(arg1, arg2) is called, python internally converts
>   it for you as:
>
> ClassA.methodA(ObjectA, arg1, arg2)

Now my confusion is why program need to call class with each method ?

Class.meth(obj, args) ??

like when we call a.distance it become Point.distance(a) causes of "self" 
when we called a.bye it become Point.bye(a) causes of "self" .

when Point class is necessery with each method if we don't use Point class with each method what will happen?

why can't simply meth(obj, args) works ?

My main doubt is why its called class.some_method with each method when we called with attribute of method . why its needs calls with each one?

*#if i am understanding right then its necessary because so that each method can access other methods data like variables and stuff?*

Comment: "it become Point.a.distance()": it doesn't do this.  it becomes `Point.distance(a)` or `type(a).distance(a)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is

> python internally converts it for you

From your standpoint:

- `meth(self, args)` is the syntax you use to *define* member functions; and
- `obj.meth(args)` is the syntax you use to *call* member functions.

The `meth(obj,args)` option is the way procedural languages work.  That is often how the implementation works, but expressing the call as `obj.meth(args)` keeps focus on the object and makes it easier to read which data values (object instances) are being used.

**Edit 1** If I understand your question correctly, you are asking why Python needs to know the *class* when it already has the *instance* available, and instances know their own types.  In fact, Python fetches methods based on the instance [all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4714147/2877364).  I think the point the tutorial is making is that in Python, the *class* is the primary place the functions are defined.  This is different from some object-oriented languages, in which each instance has its own methods, and they may be completely different from each other.  So the tutorial is contrasting the usual approach in Python:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        pass
```

with an alternative (possible in Python, but not typical):

```
foo = object()   # an empty instance
foo.bar = lambda self: pass
```

**Edit 2** Python methods normally live in the classes, not in the instances.  Even if you create 1000 `Point` objects, there is only one copy of the actual instruction bytes for `Point.distance`.  Those instruction bytes are executed anytime `<some point variable>.distance()` is called.  You are correct that the `self` parameter is how those instruction bytes know what instance to work on, and how the method can access other data in the passed instance.

**Edit 3** `self` isn't exactly a namespace in the way that local vs. global is.  However, it is fair to say that `self.foo` refers to a `foo` that is indeed accessible to all the methods of *this instance of* the current class.  Given

```
a = Point(1,2)
b = Point(3,4)
```

inside a `Point.distance` call, `self` refers to `a` or `b`, but not both.  So when you call `a.distance()`, the `self.x` will be `a.x`, not `b.x`.  But all methods of `Point` can access `self.x` to get whatever the current point's `x` is.

**Edit 4** Suppose you weren't using objects, but instead dictionaries:

```
a = {'x':1, 'y':2}  # make a "point"
b = {'x':3, 'y':4}  # make another

def point_distance(point):
    print (point['x'])
```

then you could say:

```
point_distance(a)
```

to get the effect of

```
print (a['x'])
```

Classes do basically that, with cleaner syntax and some nice benefits.  But just as the `point` parameter to `point_distance()` refers to one and only one point-like dictionary each time you call `point_distance()`, the `self` parameter to `Point.distance()` refers to one and only one `Point` instance each time you call `<whatever point>.distance()`.

Comment: My original question is Why python needs to internally converts like this ?? i mean why its necessary to attach "self" with each class??

Comment: so if i am correct then i can assume conclusion is "self" change the namespace  of local namespace to global namespace of variables for all the methods of current class . (only global for current class not for other class)

Comment: sir yes now i am very close what i really wanted to know , I think you got it exactly what i was wanted trying get to know , your last lines are actual answer what i was looking  Please explain more in brief  what you wrote in last lines , that what i needed sir , Please more explanation .

Comment: @Eleutetio try that.  Also, if you haven't yet, check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about how you can get the most out of the site!

Answer (score 2):

Because you can have the same method name in different classes, and it needs to call the appropriate one. So if you have

```
class Class1:
    def meth():
        print "This is Class 1"

class Class2:
    def meth():
        print "This is Class 2"

c1 = Class1()
c2 = Class2()
c1.meth() # equivalent to Class1.meth(c1)
c2.meth() # equivalent to Class2.meth(c2)
```

If it translated `c1.meth()` to `meth(c1)`, there's no way for the system to know *which* `meth()` function to call.

Answer (score 1):

Classes define what is common to all instances of them. Usually this is the code comprising each of its methods. To apply this code to the correct instance object, the language interprets

```
instance.method(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

as

```
class_of_instance.method(instance, arg1, arg2, ...)
```

so the code is applied to the proper class instance.