# Converting from c++ to python - How to declare a virtual method with no definition in python

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to convert a c++ library to python.

**c++ file**

```
class A
{
  public:
    virtual void example(paramtype, paramtype) = 0;
    void myMethod(void);
}

void A::myMethod(void){
    example();
}

class B: public A
{
  public:
    void example(paramtype p1, paramtype p2); // implemented
}
```

I am having hard time with implementation of **myMethod**. I thought of making a variable to hold the example method and invoke the variable in **myMethod** like below.

**python file**

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.example = None

    def myMethod(self):
        self.example()
```

But then editor says None type can't be called(of course). How can I achieve this?

Comment: `self.example = (lambda: None)`?

Comment: Looks like a good use case for python's `abc` package. From what I see, `class A` is an abstract base class. `abc` package let's you define abstract base classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base class in C++ is declaring a virtual method with no definition.

```
virtual void example(paramtype, paramtype) = 0;
```

That means it must be defined in a child class to be used. In your library, that's class `B`.

In Python, you can use

```
raise NotImplementedError()
```

to indicate that a method has not been implemented. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38717503/2773311) for more details.

```
class A:
    def example(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def myMethod(self):
        self.example()

class B(A):
    # override the example method by providing the implementation
    def example(self):
        # implementation
```

In this example, calling `example` on an object of type `A` will throw an error, because the method isn't defined. You can only invoke the method on an object of type `B`.

Comment: But I have to call example in A's implementation. Won't myMethod raise NotImplementedError?

Comment: I've updated the implementation to fix some mistakes. `self.example` will run the implementation provided in `B` if you call it on an object of type `B`.

Comment: Thank you. Best answer.

Answer (score 2):

To convert your C++ code into python3, you should derive from python's abstract base class (ABC). This lets you create abstract methods:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class A(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def example(self, a, b):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def my_method(self):
        self.example(1, 2)
```

Additional information can be found here https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html